# sqlite3_error in Ubuntu20.04

Tags: 20.04, sqlite3

I met a strange problem when using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. When I type any non-meaning word in the command line, such as a letter `A`, it returns something related to python3.8 with "ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_errstr". Please see below,

```
huan@grape:~$ A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_errstr
```

I have searched online, but I could not find the solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64428140/native-python3-fails-to-import-sqlite3-on-ubuntu-focal

I also checked the location of `_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

```
huan@grape:~$ cd /
huan@grape:/$ sudo find -name _sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
[sudo] password for huan: 
find: ‘./run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘./run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/2196/task/2196/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘./proc/2196/net’: Invalid argument
./snap/core20/1376/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
./snap/core20/1361/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
./usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
huan@grape:/$
```

It can be found in `/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload` directory and `/snap/core20/1376/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/` as well as `/snap/core20/1361/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/` directories.

My question is why the non-meaning command "A" will relate to the sqlite3 module of Python3.8? I even did nothing with SQL. How could I solve these annoying returns?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.  -- Huan

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but I don't think it is related to Ubuntu 20.04 since I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

In my case (I am working inside a conda environment) the problem is fixed by just reinstalling sqlite.

```
conda install sqlite --force-reinstall
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
However, it does not work for me.